# combining .not() and parents()

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b" nopopup>
    <div id="c"> 
      <div id="d">
```

I use a jQuery .hover() to popup a menu when particular `<div>`s are moused over. A string, $selector, identifies which `<div>`s get a hover.

```
$($selector).hover( 
  // popup the menu
)
```

That works. I now want to thwart operation of the .hover() when an ancestor `<div>` has the valueless attribute "nopopup", as `<div>` b above does. That "nopopup" would thwart any hover for c and d, even if the $selector selected them. The number of levels between the hover candidate and the thwarting nopopup varies.

I need something like:

```
$($selector).not( one of the selected node's parents has the attribute "nopopup" ).hover( 
  // popup the menu
)
```

What goes in those parentheses? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: There is no attribute nopopup, use it as a class instead: `$(selector).filter(function() { return !$(this).closest('.nopopup').length; }).hover(...`

Comment: This project is fearlessly and shamelessly using custom attributes. Time will tell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use several approaches. Following assumes that `nopopup` is a class since html isn't valid

```
$($selector).hover( 
  if( !$(this).closest('.nopopup').length){
       /* run code when nopop isn't ancestor*/
   }
)
```

OR

```
$($selector).not('.nopopup '+$selector).hover(....
```

Comment: closest() is what I needed. +1, Q answered.

Answer (score 0):

ID's cannot be reused, please note the changes.

```
​$('.d').not('div[nopopup] .d').hover(function(){
    //logic 
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pYeRv/)